# Elevated permissions required to debug an application running within a Docker container?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, remote-debugging

Are elevated permissions required in order to remote debug (with Visual Studio) an application running within a windows Docker container, using the 'Attach to Process' method?

Does the configuration of such a container define or impact whether or not elevated permissions may be required? Perhaps by configuring a user group within the container?

[This post](https://www.richard-banks.org/2017/02/debug-net-in-windows-container.html) although useful omits this information, and at least through experience of remote debugging application on servers within the same domain, Visual Studio has always prompted for elevation.